# CreateGraphics(): Graphics is shown only on re-size

Tags: c#, graphics

Instantiating the form.

```
     public TwoDPlot()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);

            InitializeComponent();

            DrawCircle();
        }
```

Method to draw the circle.

```
private void DrawCircle()
        {
            var radius = 0.5 * ClientRectangle.Width;

            var height = ClientRectangle.Height - 0.1 * ClientRectangle.Height;

            var width = ClientRectangle.Width - 0.1 * ClientRectangle.Width;

            var scaledRadius = width > height ? radius * (height / radius) : radius * (width / radius);

            var xlocation = ClientRectangle.Width / 2.0 - scaledRadius * 0.5;

            var ylocation = ClientRectangle.Height / 2.0 - scaledRadius * 0.5;

            m_Graphics = CreateGraphics();

            m_Graphics?.Clear(DefaultBackColor);

            m_Graphics?.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red), new Rectangle((int)xlocation, (int)ylocation, (int)scaledRadius, (int)scaledRadius));

            m_Graphics.Dispose();
        }
```

On instance, it shows empty form and upon re-sizing it shows the circle. I expect to show during the first instance.

Comment: Why are you disposing the m_Graphics object?

Comment: Removing the Dispose() method call is not changing anything either. Still empty form on new instance.

Comment: Put the DrawCirCircle() in a form load method instead of the constructor.  The circle needs to be drawn after the constructor terminates.  The form constructor has additional code that gets run after the constructor in your code gets executed.

Comment: Load += (sender, args) => DrawCircle();

No change in the behavior.

Comment: The resize will force the paint event to update the form so that is why you see the object.  I not sure why the circle is not showing initially since the CreateGraphics should also call the paint event.  The form constructor is calling the default paint method.  I suspect the resize method is calling a different paint method or something is changing in the main code (like size or color change) that is allowing the circle to appear.  Just changing a property of a control won't cause the paint method to automatically update the form.  So the change isn't recognized until the resize is performed.

Comment: __NEVER__ use  `CreateGraphics()` ! It does have its uses but not for you, not for creating persistent graphics. Period. Always use the `Paint` event and its `e.Graphics` object plus data to control what you draw. - @jdweng: Before giving advice you should learn the __basics__ yourself. Everything you wrote is 100% wrong.

Comment: Seems to be so. May I have an example that uses `Paint` to draw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the direct correction:

```
private void TwoDPlot_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DrawCircle(e.Graphics);
}


private void DrawCircle(Graphics m_Graphics)
{
    var radius = 0.5 * ClientRectangle.Width;
    var height = ClientRectangle.Height - 0.1 * ClientRectangle.Height;
    var width = ClientRectangle.Width - 0.1 * ClientRectangle.Width;
    var scaledRadius = width > height ? radius * (height / radius) : radius * (width / radius);
    var xlocation = ClientRectangle.Width / 2.0 - scaledRadius * 0.5;
    var ylocation = ClientRectangle.Height / 2.0 - scaledRadius * 0.5;

    m_Graphics.Clear(DefaultBackColor);
    m_Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red), new Rectangle((int)xlocation, (int)ylocation, (int)scaledRadius, (int)scaledRadius));
}
```

Note that to be more flexible you will want to move the variables maybe to class level variables or to parameters to the `DrawCircle` function..

**When** you have done that **and** changed the variables values you can trigger the `Paint` event by calling `TwoDPlot.Invalidate()`.

The **system** will **also** call it whenever it needs to, e.g. upon many resize, maximize and other events..

Comment: Works.  What is actually `CreateGraphics()` doing? May be I should read it in more detail.

Comment: Yes, a puzzling method for newbies. It creates a Graphics that is related to a Control's surface; it is used to either draw __non-persistent__ graphics like a rubberband rectangle etc or to measure things like strings. Anything you want to persist needs to be redrawn when the system needs to do that like after a minimize/maximize must be either drawn onto the control in the Paint event with its always current e.Graphics object or into a Bitmap that is shown as sme sort of Image.

Comment: Note that I had left the Dispose in the DrawCircle erroneously. It is wrong; never dispose of a thing you didn't create! Corrected.

Comment: Another problem is zooming the selected area on client rectangle. I have some sample code to zoom the selected area on an image but do we zoom into the selected area?

Comment: This is always a little fickely to code but there are various solutions here on  SO. The basic idea is: Get the zoom factor and use it to scale the Graphics object with ScaleTransform. also calculate the __scaled__ new origin (ie the topLeft corner of the zoom area and TranslateTransform the Graphics by that amount..